# Where do I get Tuvala Gear?

Tags: black-desert-online

This page from BDO talks about how to get the Tuvala Ore to enhance the gear, but where do I get the gear itself?

https://www.blackdesertonline.com/news/view/4034

I understand that this is only for the seasonal characters/servers, but I can't find the gear

Answer (score 1):

I found that some Tuvala gear is gifted through the main Event NPC Fughar's quests, while the majority will probably be obtained through exchanges with him:

- 1x Tuvala Ore for a Tuvala gear piece
- 5x Tuvala Ore for a Tuvala accessory

(You will need multiple pieces for repairing max durability on your main gear pieces)

Tuvala Ore is also obtained through Fughar's quests, and through grinding in certain spots.  In the link I posted in the question look for the section "Where Do I Get Materials for Tuvala Equipment?" which shows which areas drop Tuvala Ore.  There are different places to grind for Time-filled Black Stone, Refined Magical Black Stone, and **Tuvala Ore**. **YOU MUST BE ON SEASONAL SERVERS TO GET THE DROPS.**

Time-filled Black Stone and Refined Magical Black Stone are used for enhancing the Tuvala gear.